# Where to get additional information about php-fpm log messages?

Tags: php, php-fpm

Shortly: where can I get additional information about php-fpm log messages?

**Details**

I'm encountering some php-fpm issues, and with normal log level almost nothing is written in the log. So I set log level to `debug` to try and get additional informations.

Unfortunately some of the log entries are not really self-explaining. I searched extensively on Google and PHP.net site for documentation or reference but could not find any.

Is there an official or unofficial main resource about explaining php-fpm debug log messages?

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Google is usually pretty good. Failing that the source code.

Comment: A bit useless, but thank you anyway. I searched extensively on Google and on PHP.net site before posting here. Browsing the source code is always a last option, but I feel that if I really have to do that, what's the point in having any kind of messages in the log at all? We could just put error codes and of course all sysadmins in the world will take the habit of keeping a cloned repo of php-fpm available for reference.

Comment: `debug` log level is mainly meant to help those who are already familiar with PHP internals, and those people know how to read it. That is likely the reason there isn't that much documentation about it. Maybe you should ask about the issues themselves here...

Comment: @TeroKilkanen that makes sense. The problem is that without debug I don't even have any clue as to what is happening and, thus, where to start tweaking / fixing. Thank you for your suggestion, I may ask separate questions for specific issues.